# Declaring int values before the main() function VS after C++

Tags: c++, integer

What is the difference between this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n, d, nr;

int main()
{
    cin >> n;
    
    for(d = 1; d * d < n; d++){
        if (n % d == 0){
            if (d % 2 == 0) nr++;
            if (n / d % 2 == 0) nr++;
        }
    }
    if (d * d == n && d % 2 == 0) nr++;
    
    cout << nr;
}
```

And this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, d, nr;
    cin >> n;
    
    for(d = 1; d * d < n; d++){
        if (n % d == 0){
            if (d % 2 == 0) nr++;
            if (n / d % 2 == 0) nr++;
        }
    }
    if (d * d == n && d % 2 == 0) nr++;
    
    cout << nr;
}
```

I input 12 and expect 4. The first one works the second one doesn't.

Declaring the `n`, `d`, `nr` integers before `main()` returns a different value versus declaring them after the `main()` function. Why?

Comment: The ones declared before are initialized.  The ones declared after are uninitialized.  Initialization matters.

Comment: You should be trying to keep your definitions as close as possible to their first use, and their scope as narrow as practical. Making these variables global is not warranted, nor helpful. For example: `for (int d = 1; ...)` is better.

Comment: Side note: Avoid global variables. You're generally better off with the variables declared local to a function and explicitly initialized.

Comment: Tip: Don't cram your expressions together so tightly. `if(d*d==n&&d%2==0) nr++;` is borderline noise. `if (d*d == n && d%2 == 0) nr++;` makes it much easier to see what's actually going on.

Comment: Bad example, @tadman . `d` looks like it outlives the scope of the for loop.

Comment: @user4581301 Yeah, but it probably *shouldn't*. There's something weird going on here with the use of a loop variable way down there. If the loop terminates normally, `d*d == n` is a given. The reason I suggested defining `d` in the loop exposes inconsistencies like this.

Comment: Agree. The end of the loop is pretty tightly related to `n`.

Answer (score 4):

Variables declared outside of a function or class have "file scope" lifetime. This basically means that they are global variables.

Integers with file scope are initialized as `0`, and as a result `int n,d,nr;` are all initialized to `0` in the first example.

Of particular interest is `nr`, because it is otherwise unassigned to. This means that it has an indeterminate value when declared inside of `main`

---

(Edited to add standardese)

More formally, `int n,d,nr;` in the top example have *namespace scope*. That is, the smallest scope they are declared in is the global scope/global namespace. (Per [[basic.scope]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.scope#namespace-1) and [[basic.namespace]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.namespace#general-3)).

Variables with namespace scope are defined to have *static storage duration* (per [[basic.stc.static]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.static))

Variables with *static storage duration* are zero initialized at program start (per [[basic.start.static]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static#2)).

Answer (score 1):

The difference is when you define your variables before main(at global scope) they just get zeroed for you. But when you define your variables in a function without an initial value their value will vary.

Your problem is that nr variables is not initialized with zero value. just do nr=0;